# Parent and child with different Animators

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

I'm animating my 2D game (Unity 5.4).

Is it a good/bad practice to have parent and child gameobjects with different Animators?

Example: a 2D bug, that has sprites for every body part. On the "body container"=parent object I add an Animator and animate all parts except the head. For the head, that is a child gameobject to the body (in scene's hierarchy) I want to add a separate Animator and animate only the head.

Also is that influencing performance in any way?

Answer (score 1):

On the side of performance, there is no impact, if you have multiple animator components on child objects and on the parent too. The questions is rather, do you need this?

Why should you just animate the head from the rest of the body? If you can answer this question in your case in any situation with yes, then go on an do what you want. If you can't find an answer leading to yes and it is just because it is easier to animate for you in such a case, go on and do it.